# gulp-git, clone progression output?

Tags: git, gulp

I use `gulp-git` to clone git repo's, however some of these repo's can be rather large. I need to display some kind of progression to the user so they know it hasn't just hung.

This is the code to perform the clone:

```
gulp.git.clone('repo.git', { args: 'path', quiet: false });
```

But this just displays the following:

```
[12:14:25] Using gulpfile ~\code\websites\gulpfile.js
[12:14:25] Starting 'get'...
[12:14:25] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[12:14:25] Cloning theme _themev2-website-111, please wait...
```

However performing the `git` command: `git clone repo.git` displays some nice progress figures, which gulp should do considering it's just running this same command.

```
Cloning into '_website-746'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 125, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (125/125), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (117/117), done.
Receiving objects:   5% (7/125), 2.14 MiB | 1.05 MiB/s
```

I believe that when you run `gulp.git` commands they are run on a separate thread or command line instance, as console logging this does give you access to a **process id**, is there a way to use this ID to get any logging from this process, which I can then display within the same gulp process?